# create instance of a class based on the another class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, instance

In Java I have class `X` and interface `Y` and then a set of classes `A1`.. And that extend `X` and implement `Y`. 
I then make a wrapper/adapter for each of the classes `A1..An`  (i.e., `A1'..An'`).

Now, in the client class `C`, I receive the list of instances of interface `Y` (`ArrayList < Y >`).

At this place, for each instance in the list, I want to create new instance of a class `Ax'` (from `A1'..An'`) based on fact which instance of `Y` is in the list. For `A1` to make `A1'` etc.

My doubt is how can I achieve this without `if`..`else if`... and (instance of) construction. Can I use inheritance here somehow?

I was checking some design patterns but I couldn't find solution how to create the classes based on which instance are another classes.

Any help and advise would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you want to create classes dynamically!???? Is that the question???? what are you asking??

Comment: By `A1'` do you mean that it will do something differently than A1 or that it will do the same thing as A1?

Comment: A1' should have instance of A1 inside and have some other functionalities

Comment: Thanks, I'm writing an appropriate answer now.

Comment: Who is parent and who is child?

Comment: @llya well A1' should add some functionality and reuse some of A1 so it can either contain it's instance or extend it...

Answer (score 2):

```
for(Y y : ArrayList < Y >)  
{  
   y.getClass().newInstance();  
}
```

if I understood your question correctly...

**EDIT**

```
abstract class X implements Y 
{
    Y getInstance();
}

class A1 extends X
{
    void someMethod()
    {
        getInstance(); // return instance of A1_
    }
}

class A1_ extends A1
{
    Y getInstance()
    {
        return new A1_();
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

If you want get parent's instance in child, you can do

```
this.getClass().getSuperclass().newInstance();
```

Comment: no no instead creating instances of Y, I want to create A1' ... An',
based on which instance is y

Comment: @krcun This actually creates a new instance of whatever `y` is. If `y` is an instance of `A2`, then this will create a new `A2`.

Comment: `Y` is interface, you will create instance of child class

Comment: I'm not sure what OP is doing with the "wrapper/adapter".  Since the Ys are actually instances of an An' (i.e., a wrapper) and wrappers usually need to _wrap_ something, it's seems unlikely that the default constructor, say for class A2', will do what he wants (or even exist).

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention in the original question that I cannot make changes to X,Y or A1..An.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.forName()` method to create wrapper. The mapping between class A1..AN and class name of wrapper may be stored either hard coded, in properties or XML file or if you want using annotation placed on your A1...AN classes.

Comment: thanks. How would this annotation will work? The point is that I need to add new functionalities without making changes to A1..An.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Y y : ArrayList < Y >)  
{  
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(y.getClass().getName()+"Adapter");
  YAdapter ya = (YAdapter)clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Mixing both answers.

Comment: Assuming the developer has some pattern of how those adapters are named. That's an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Create `HashMap<Class<Y>, Class<?>>`. For each An and A'n, create relation: `map.put(An.class, A'n.class)`.

Then, for each `obj` in ArrayList , get A' class: `Class aa=map.get(obj.getClass())`. Then create instance of class aa, either with `aa.newInstance()` (and then pass `obj` via setter), or with a constructor using reflection (and pass `obj` as a parameter).

Comment: This seems as a nicer solution. I would just need to keep this map somewhere and to update it when I add new Ax' classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a way to associate the adapters (A'<sub>1</sub> .. A'<sub>n</sub>) with the concrete instances (A<sub>1</sub> .. A<sub>n</sub>). This is best done using a `Map<Class<?>, Constructor<?>>`. A good way would be to write a registry around it:

```
public class AdapterRegistry {
    private static final Map<Class<?>, Constructor<?>> adapterMap =
            new HashMap<Class<?>, Constructor<?>>();

    public static void register(Class<?> interfaceClass, Class<?> concreteClass, Class<?> adapterClass) 
            throws NoSuchMethodException {
        // Check for the constructor
        Constructor<?> constructor = adapterClass.getConstructor(interfaceClass);
        adapterMap.put(concreteClass, constructor);
    }

    public static <T, V extends T> T wrap(V v) {
        Class<?> concreteClass = v.getClass();
        try {
            Constructor<?> constructor = adapterMap.get(concreteClass);
            if (constructor != null) {
                return (T) constructor.newInstance(v);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO Log me
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of creating the adapters:

```
public class Adapter implements Y {
    private Y innerY;

    public Adapter(Y innerY) {
        this.innerY = innerY;
    }

    // Implement Y
}
```

And register your Adapter(s):

```
AdapterRegistry.register(Y.class, A1.class, Adapter1.class);
AdapterRegistry.register(Y.class, A2.class, Adapter1.class);
AdapterRegistry.register(Y.class, A3.class, Adapter2.class);
// ...
AdapterRegistry.register(An.class, AdapterM.class);
```

Notice how you can register multiple adapters for the same class like this if you like. That way if a subset of concrete classes will be handled the same way, you just have to register the same adapter for all of them.

Next, get the wrapper:

```
for (Y y : yList) {
    Y adapter = AdapterRegistry.wrap(y);
    // Do something with the adapter
}
```

This has certain restrictions:

- You must have a constructor in each adapter that takes the concrete object *by its interface*.
- The interface must have the methods you're looking to change (if you use `Y` as the type for `innerY`, you can change this so that you have access to non-interface methods, but then you have to do casting).

You can then also use your `AdapterRegistry` in other parts of your program too, due to its use of generics.

Let me know if there's any problems with the code and you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

One standard solution to avoid if/else-chains in situations like this, is to make the classes implement some interface containing a method which makes the objects know what to do themselves - i.e. to use inheritance as you suggest.

The concrete classes knows their own concrete types, how to copy themselves, etc, but you don't know that in the loop - so it makes sense to move the responsibility of creating new concrete classes to the concrete classes themselves.

What i would do is to add a new method to the `Y` interface which creates the new instance.
For example, if you just want to take a copy of the instances in the list you could add a "copy" factory-method to `Y`:

```
public interface Y {
    ...
    public Y copy();
    ...
}
```

Each implementation of `Y` must implement the copy method. It knows how to copy itself. Example:

```
public class MyClass implements Y {
    ...
    public MyClass copy() {
        return new MyClass(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

So creating new instances when iterating through the list then simply becomes something like this:

```
List<Y> ys = ...get list from somewhere...;
for (Y y : ys) {
    Y copy = y.copy();
    ...
}
```

Note that there is no reflection or other hacks needed with this approach.

Also note that the loop does not have to know anything about the concrete classes - it only have to know about the interface `Y`. All the code specific to the concrete classes are kept inside the concrete classes themselves. This makes the code using them simpler (avoids the instanceof + if/else chains).

Instead of a copy method, you could of course also create more advanced methods, perhaps taking some parameters. This could be useful if the objects don't just have to copy themselves, but have to create the new instance of themselves in some special way based on some input.

(Note: This copy method might remind you of "clone", but since clone in Java is quite broken, this is usually a better approach)

Note: I have assumed that both the `Ai'` wrappers and `Ai` extends `Y`.

Note: If you can't make changes to `Y`, but can change the adapter classes, you can make a new interface `Y'` which extends `Y` and which the adapter-classes implement, and use a `List<Y'>` instead of `List<Y>` which you iterate over those in the loop.